# Negative items in matrix replaced

Tags: python, list, matrix

Here is the given piece of assignment + code:

> Write a procedure `replace_negatives(matrix)`, which receives a matrix
> with integer items as an argument.
>
> The function replaces all negative items in the matrix with their
> absolute values (for example -1 is replaced with 1 and -7 with 7).
>
> ```
> def test():
>
>    m = []
>    size = random.randint(4,7)
>    for i in range(size):
>        m.append([0] * size)
>        for j in range(size):
>            m[i][j] = random.randint(-10,10)
>    print ("Matrix before:")
>    output_matrix(m)
>    print ("")
>    
>    replace_negatives(m)
>    print ("Matrix after:")
>    output_matrix(m)
>    
> def output_matrix(m):
>
>    for row in m:
>        print (row)
>        
> test()
>
>
>
> import random
>
>
>
> # next line generates a random number
> # and assigns it to variable n1
> n1 = random.randint(50,150)
> ```

This is what I did:

```
def replace_negatives(matrix):
    

    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        if matrix[i] < 0:
             matrix[i] = matrix[i] * (-1)
             
             return(matrix)
```

but it gives me:

```
  line 43, in
    test()
  File "/tmp/untrusted/test095033c3f-464a-4fb4-8a1d-ddd8385d21a7/test.py", line 35, in test
    replace_negatives(m)
  File "/tmp/untrusted/test095033c3f-464a-4fb4-8a1d-ddd8385d21a7/test.py", line 18, in replace_negatives
    if matrix[i] < 0:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not indexing the matrix correctly. `matrix[i]` refers to the ith row in matrix.

```py
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix)):
        if matrix[i][j] < 0:
            matrix[i][j] = abs(matrix[i][j])
```

The above code will work for square matrices, however, you can change the inner loop to get the number of columns.

Comment: Ahh, true, that makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do :

```py
matrix = np.absolute(matrix)
```